# Integrate $\int\frac{dx}{2x^3-6x+4}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need some help with the following indefinite integral

$$\int\frac{dx}{2x^3-6x+4}$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: Note that $1$ is a root of the equation $2x^3-6x+4=0$ and use partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 2):

Hint; Write it as 
$$\int \left ( \frac {1}{18(x+2)} - \frac {1}{18(x-1)} + \frac {1}{6(x-1)^2} \right ) dx$$

It's easy now, take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\Large \frac{1}{2x^3-6x+4} \equiv \frac{1}{18(x+2)}-\frac{1}{18(x-1)}+\frac{1}{6(x-1)^2}$$

---

You can check this identity by factorising $2x^3-6x+4$ as $2(x+2)(x-1)^2.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Partial fraction decomposition should be your friend since the roots of the denominator are $1$ and $-2$ as you should have found by simple inspection.